# How to do arithmetic manipulations on entire rows in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I have a table of data which I want to do some arithmetic manipulations on.

If I want to subtract say `11B` from `3B` I just do `=$B3-$B11`.
But if I want to subtract each row 11 value from its corresponding row 3 value how do I do this? `$Each3-$Each11`

I don't want to have to input a formula in each box.

Comment: AFAIK you can only do that by copying the value of the cell where you put the formula and paste it into all of the cells where you want the formula to be (by click and drag).

Comment: This isn't relevant to Linux or Unix. LibreOffice is fully capable of running on any major operating system. This should possibly be on SuperUser instead.

Comment: Retracting close vote as per [discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15322037#15322037)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy - just drag and drop the formula. So, starting with these values:

[image]

and assuming the difference betweeen rows 11 and 3, 13 and 5 should appear in `A16:K18`, you should start putting the formula "`=A11-A3`" into `A16`:

[image]

Now, click little black rectangle in the lower right corner of the black frame around `A16`, hold and drag to the right, stopping in `K16`:

[image]

Finally, click again on the little black rectangle, now in the lower right corner of K16, and drag down to `K18`. As result, OpenOffice Calc will apply the formula to both rows 11 and 13, calculating the difference to the values 11 rows up:

[image]